# How do I consume events from a late-bound COM object?

Tags: vb6, event-handling, late-binding

I have a late-bound COM object (`My.COMInterface`) which raises an event when it has finished processing. How do I consume that event from VB6 code?

If I was early-binding, I would declare my COM object as WithEvents, and write a normal event-handler. How can I achieve this using late-binding?

**Current code:**

```
Dim comObject as Object

'Function to launch Process.
Public Function LaunchProcess() As Boolean
    Set comObject = CreateObject("My.COMInterface")

    LaunchProcess= comObject.CallProcess()
    ' Once this process has finished, it will raise an event 
    ' called ProcessingFinished - how do I consume it?
End Function
```

The only way I know to do it currently is to write a C/C++ bridge to handle the events, as described in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301508.aspx). I'm hoping for a simpler method!

Comment: +1. I don't know any way besides what is described in the MSDN article. Did you notice the section in the article about using VBScript? You could have a VBScript bridge communicating with the VB6 using the [Microsoft Script Control](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=d7e31492-2595-49e6-8c02-1426fec693ac&displaylang=en). Tutorial on using the script control from VB6 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227421(VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 3):

If it's a plain COM object, I've not seen any way in native VB6.
If the object was a control however, you could use the `VBControlExtender` interface and the `ObjectEvent` event.

Comment: Plain COM object I'm afraid. Looks like this won't be possible which is a shame - why is it easy in VBScript, but impossible natively for VB6?!!

Comment: I didn't realise VBScript supports it for late bound object. How do you assign a handler to an event?

Comment: @Deanna See the code in the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301508.aspx) provided in RB's question, in the section "a Windows Script Host solution"

Answer (score 1):

Look at [EventCollection Class v2.0 - Add event support to Collections](http://www.mvps.org/emorcillo/en/code/vb6/index.shtml) by E. Morcillo.

Should do what you want and more.